# ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() returns null for Ethernet connection

Tags: android, network-programming, ethernet

The following code works fine for Wi-Fi connection:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

However, activeNetworkInfo is always null on an Android 4.2.2 tablet when it is connected to a router via an Ethernet cable.  The connection works fine (i.e. all network related functions such as browsing web pages work fine).  Could anyone shed some light on this and offer a tip on how to tell whether an Android device is connected to a network reliably?

Comment: i use this code maybe 10 month ago...
wifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
..
how about request to your server and catch error.

Comment: @jihoonkim that should work. I hope there is a quick and reliable way. Some uses, I need to detect the connection almost instantly to inform user if there is no network connection.  The current method generates a false alarm.